# SQL Server query optimization?

Tags: sql-server, sql-optimization

I have the following query:

```
SELECT
  tl.*, d.*
FROM
  TrackerLocations AS tl
  inner join Trackers t on tl.TrackerId = t.TrackerId
  inner join Devices d on t.UserId = d.UserId
WHERE
  tl.ReceivedTime = (SELECT MAX(tl2.ReceivedTime) FROM TrackerLocations tl2 WHERE tl2.TrackerId = tl.TrackerId)
  and tl.ReceivedTime >= DATEADD (MINUTE,-2,GETUTCDATE())
  and d.OSType <> 3
  and d.Notify = 1
```

...and for my surprise, it does not return the results in an acceptable time. First times I runned it in production environment, was like 3 seconds of execution. Now, it runs until timeout (inside C# application, 30 seconds).
The main purpose is: "give me the most recent locations from any tracker and info about it's users's devices, looking 2 minutes backwards".
Any hints about optimizing this query?

Thanks!

**Indexes:**
Anywhere but where clause columns (ReceivedTime, OSType, Notify).

About the execution plan, it's a huge thing and it's not too familiar to me. Should I paste it here? :)

Comment: use common table expressions to limit the number of rows being joined.

Comment: What indexes do you have? What does the execution plan look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT tl.*,d.*
 FROM
    TrackerLocations AS tl
    inner join Trackers t on tl.TrackerId = t.TrackerId
    inner join Devices d on t.UserId = d.UserId
 WHERE
    tl.ReceivedTime = (SELECT MAX(tl2.ReceivedTime) 
                         FROM TrackerLocations tl2 
                        WHERE tl2.TrackerId = tl.TrackerId 
                          and tl2.ReceivedTime >= @searchTerm)
    and d.RegistrationId <> ''
    and d.OSType <> 3
    and d.Notify = 1
```

Comment: Indeed! Restricting the "select max" clause with ReceivedTime >= ... makes this inner select a lot less painful, apparently.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest trying an index on (`TrackerId`, `ReceivedTime`) and maybe just `ReceivedTime` as well. But, without profiling and an actual execution plan it's just a shot in the dark.

Answer (score 1):

Create indexes on `TrackerLocations.TrackerId` and `Trackers.TrackerId`.  Also `Devices.UserId` and `Trackers.UserId` for the 2nd `JOIN`.  Finally, look at creating an index on `TrackerLocations.ReceivedTime` as well for the `WHERE` clause.

In general, the first place to look to optimize queries like this is checking to see if you have indexes on your join criteria.  Also, if you have some sort of filter (`WHERE` clause), that could be another place to add an index.

It's hard to say exactly where you need to optimize without looking at the query execution plan.  A lot of factors can feed into it, including how many records are in each table.  Don't go too crazy creating indexes, though -- they have a performance impact, for example when inserting new data.  Best advice is to just test with different indexes, and see if the execution plan gives you some hints.

Comment: Thank you John and Michael, I'll try (first of all) index on ReceivedTime later and post the results here!

Answer (score 1):

because I don't know what the execution plan looks like for this query I can only go on what I feel would help speed up the results.

1. Do you have primary keys and foreign key constraints
2. Are those keys then indexed

beyond that I would try and use a CTE to limit the results being joined together something to the effect of **(Not Tested)**:

```
;WITH cte_loc AS
(
    SELECT
        tl.*
    FROM
        TrackerLocations tl            
    WHERE
        tl.ReceivedTime >= DATEADD (MINUTE,-2,GETUTCDATE())
),cte_loc2 AS
(
    SELECT
        TrackerId
        ,MAX(ReceivedTime) AS MaxReceivedTime
    FROM
        cte_loc
    GROUP BY
        TrackerId
),cte_dev AS
(
    SELECT
        tl.TrackerId,
        d.*
    FROM
        cte_loc2 tl 
            INNER JOIN Trackers t ON tl.TrackerId = t.TrackerId
            INNER JOIN Devices d ON t.UserId = d.UserId             
    WHERE
        d.OSType <> 3 AND d.Notify = 1
)

SELECT
    tl.*, d.*
FROM
    cte_loc AS tl      
        INNER JOIN cte_loc2 tl2 ON tl.TrackerId = tl2.TrackerId
                               AND tl.ReceivedTime = tl2.MaxReceivedTime
        LEFT JOIN cte_dev d ON tl.TrackerId = d.TrackerId
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are looking for the latest ReceivedTime within the last 2 minutes, you're going to want to create an index on `ReceivedTime` in DESC order. The DESC order part is important. It will also help with the MAX function. You can also try an index on `(ReceivedTime DESC, TrackerID)`.