# Mysql joining two tables and counting total records based on primary key

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables `vendor` and `medicines` on mysql database now i need to count total medicines transacted based on vendor ID with a condition status is equal to paid, in a single query and show it to my users

My vendor table looks like this

```
| ID |   vendor_name    |
+----+------------------+
|  1 | Marakel Medicine |
|  2 | Ignacio Pharmacy |
|  3 | Rico Medicines   |
|  4 | Marco Pharmacy   |
+----+------------------+
```

My Medicines table looks like this.

```
| ID | vendor_id | medicine_name  | Status  |
+----+-----------+----------------+---------+
|  1 |         1 | paracetamol #1 | paid    |
|  2 |         1 | paracetamol #1 | paid    |
|  3 |         2 | paracetamol #1 | pending |
|  4 |         2 | paracetamol #1 | paid    |
|  5 |         4 | paracetamol #1 | paid    |
+----+-----------+----------------+---------+
```

My desire output would be like this

```
+----+------------------+-----------+
| ID |   vendor_name    | Total Med |
+----+------------------+-----------+
|  1 | Marakel Medicine |         2 |
|  2 | Ignacio Pharmacy |         1 |
|  3 | Rico Medicines   |         0 |
|  4 | Marco Pharmacy   |         1 |
+----+------------------+-----------+
```

So far my code is below i was able to output per vendor i just don't have an idea how to count them based on there status, any suggestion would be great!

```
SELECT * FROM vendors LEFT JOIN medicine ON vendor.ID = medicines.vendor_id
```

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Join Operation on tables based on **status**[paid or pending] & **vendor name** :

Proposed Query :

```
SELECT        vendor.ID, vendor.vendor_name, 
COUNT((CASE WHEN [status] <> 'pending' THEN 1 END)) AS 'Total Med'

FROM            medicines RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                vendor ON medicines.vendor_id = vendor.ID

GROUP BY vendor.vendor_name, vendor.ID
```

[image]

Note:
This query has been worked out in MSSQL, you can refer the logic and try for MySQL.

Corresponding **MySQL** Syntax:

```
SELECT vendor.ID, vendor.vendor_name, 
COUNT((CASE WHEN status <> 'pending' THEN 1 END)) AS 'Total Med' 
FROM medicines 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN vendor ON 
medicines.vendor_id = vendor.ID GROUP BY vendor.vendor_name, vendor.ID
```

[image]

Comment: This worked great, thanks! is there a way to optimize the query is slow since this will be a big database in the future.

Comment: happy to see that query saved your time. before optimising query i would suggest you to understand the logic and try some similar examples. Regarding optimising query, several steps can be done like indexing or working out parts where atmost delay occur, some SO posts for your help :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3801188/sql-query-optimization  ; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18152633/sql-server-query-optimization

Comment: Note that nobody ever uses RIGHT JOIN

Comment: @Strawberry any wrong in query ? please share your thoughts ..Thanks

Comment: It would be more usual to write that something like this: SELECT v.ID
     , v.vendor_name
     , SUM(status <> 'pending') 'Total Med' 
  FROM vendor v
  LEFT
  JOIN medicines m
    ON m.vendor_id = v.ID 
 GROUP 
    BY v.ID
     , v.vendor_name; Also, there's a functional dependency on vendor_name, so its inclusion in the GROUP BY isn't strictly necessary - but good practice all the same.

Comment: @Strawberry, am just a beginner in sql query building.. will keep your note in mind.. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use `GROUP BY` and `COUNT`

```
SELECT
    v.ID,
    v.vendor_name,
    COUNT(m.vendor_id) AS 'Total Med'
FROM
    vendors v
LEFT JOIN medicine m ON v.ID = m.vendor_id
GROUP BY
    v.ID
```

Comment: query will not fetch output as needed by OP

Answer (score 1):

you should try this

```
SELECT v.ID,v.vendor_name,COUNT(m.ID) as `Total`
FROM vendor v LEFT JOIN medicines m ON v.ID=m.vendor_id
GROUP BY m.ID
```

Comment: Its giving me the `unknow column vendor.ID` error still working on it and trying to get it to work.

Comment: may be your column name for that vendor table is in small, please check that column name,

Answer (score 1):

MYSQL version of @tharif's MSSQL solution.

```
SELECT
    v.ID,
    v.vendor_name,
    COUNT((CASE WHEN m.`status` <> 'pending' THEN 1 END)) AS 'Total Med'
FROM
    vendor v
LEFT JOIN medicines m ON v.ID = m.vendor_id
GROUP BY v.ID
```

It is a good idea to read on [group by](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-group-by.aspx) and [count](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-count) if you are new to these.

Answer (score 0):

Use Group By its an sql function and also use count its also an sql built in function..some similar shown below.

```
    SELECT vendors.id,vendors.vendor_name,COUNT(medicine.vendor_id) AS 'Total Transaction'
    FROM vendors LEFT JOIN medicine ON vendors.id = medicine.vendor_id 
    GROUP BY vendors.id
```

Comment: its was just for the sake of example the user who posted the question indeed know what baically id or ID is

Comment: is it ok now just added the table names for your satisfaction